# How to convert the TimeStamp to datetime2 in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to convert the TimeStamp datatype to Data time 2 using Pyspark, I did not find the solution, please help me.

Here is my Date column data

```
2018-01-02 10:00:00
```

I want to convert the timestamp to datetime2(7).

here I  tried code:

```
df=spark.sql("SELECT convert(datetime2, KeyPromotionStartDate, 7) AS StartDate from df_promotions").show()
```

Comment: datetime2(7) is not defined in pyspark data types. Check out this link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html. On another note why do you need to do the conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Does it have this kind of error?

> conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
> string. at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.sqlserverexception

Then all you need is to use date format without the time, this was helpful when solving lower and upper bound in spark sql